# extract an element from javascript to write in other part of the html page

Tags: javascript, html

I try to extract an element (display the countdown) included inside this script. It could be across a new function.
What is the process. `charsLen` is the function to extract and can be call across a new div id
I am bad in `JS`.

Thank you.

`HTML` and `JS` code:

In this case the countdown is just displayed under the textarea

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>With <code>maxChars</code> property defined:</p>
                    <textarea class="form-control countdown" rows="6"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <script>
        /*jslint browser: true*/
        /*global define, module, exports*/
        (function (root, factory) {
            "use strict";
            if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
                define([], factory);
            } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
                module.exports = factory();
            } else {
                root.VCountdown = factory();
            }
        }(this, function () {
            "use strict";
    
            var VCountdown = function (options) {
                if (!this || !(this instanceof VCountdown)) {
                    return new VCountdown(options);
                }
    
                if (!options) {
                    options = {};
                }
    
                if (!options.target) {
                    throw 'Provide a target to count characters';
                }
    
                this.target   = document.querySelector(options.target);
                this.maxChars = options.maxChars || 140;
    
                this.countdown();
            };
    
            VCountdown.prototype = {
                hasClass: function (el, name) {
                    return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name + '(\\s|$)').test(el.className);
                },
                addClass: function (el, name) {
                    if (!this.hasClass(el, name)) {
                        el.className += (el.className ? ' ' : '') + name;
                    }
                },
                removeClass: function (el, name) {
                    if (this.hasClass(el, name)) {
                        el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name + '(\\s|$)'), ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                    }
                },
                createEls: function (name, props) {
                    var el = document.createElement(name), p;
                    for (p in props) {
                        if (props.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                            el[p] = props[p];
                        }
                    }
                    return el;
                },
                insertAfter: function (referenceNode, newNode) {
                    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
                },
                update: function () {
                    var target = this.target,
                        currentCount = target.value.length,
                        remaining    = this.maxChars - currentCount;
    
                    if (remaining > 10) {
                        this.removeClass(target.nextElementSibling, 'warn');
                    } else {
                        this.addClass(target.nextElementSibling, 'warn');
                    }
    
                    target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = remaining;
                },
                setMaxChars: function () {
                    this.target.setAttribute('maxlength', this.maxChars);
                },
    
    /*display the count down*/
                charsLen: function () {
                    var span = this.createEls('span', {className: 'chars-length'});
                    span.innerHTML = this.maxChars;
    
                    this.insertAfter(this.target, span);
    
                    this.update();
                },
                countdown: function () {
                    this.setMaxChars();
                    this.charsLen();
    
                    this.target.addEventListener('keyup', this.update.bind(this), false);
                }
            };
    
            return VCountdown;
        }));
    </script>
```

to display the element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    VCountdown({
        target: '.countdown',
        maxChars: <?php echo $min_caracters_to_write; ?>
    });
</script>
```

I tried this inside the js, not work and call by

```
<div id="decreaseCount"></div>
```

not work

```
  countdown: function () {
            this.setMaxChars();
            //this.charsLen();

            //this.target.addEventListener('keyup', this.update.bind(this), false);
        }
        decreaseCount: function () {
            this.charsLen();

            this.target.addEventListener('keyup', this.update.bind(this), false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi functions defined on prototype can be accessed as below :

```
 VCountdown.prototype.countdown
```

Comment: It's across new function inside the js How to make that ?

Comment: var VCountdown = function (options)  here you defined a function Vcountdown, and then added method coundtown to its prototype  so you can use VCountdown.prototype.countdown to access countdown

Comment: ok charsLen: function coundown must be removed and replaced inside a new function if I want to display this element otherwise ?

Comment: @Harry did not get your point pls explain ?